# Strange errors after installing Jquery Mobile via package manger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, razor

I'm trying to create a mobile version of my current site.  I followed the steps in the following article, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx.  For some reason whenever I open the site in the ElectricPlum emulator I just get the .ui-loading screen and the following two errors in the developer tools console

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined**

I really don't understand how this is possible because as of right now all I have is the default generated _Laout.Mobile and a home page called Index.Mobile that has nothing but

### lorem ipsum

on it. I'm happy to provide code if it's needed, has anybody else ever run into this problem and know how in the world to fix it?

Below is my Layou.Mobile.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        @Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderSection("featured", false)
            @RenderBody()       
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

_ViewSwitcher.cshtml

```
@if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
{
    <div class="view-switcher ui-bar-a">
        @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice)
        {
            @: Displaying mobile view
            @Html.ActionLink("Desktop view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = false, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        } 
        else 
        {
            @: Displaying desktop view
            @Html.ActionLink("Mobile view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = true, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        }
    </div>
}
```

Index.Mobile.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index.Mobile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index.Mobile</h2>


<ul id="test" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check versions of jquery and jquery mobile used in that tutorial.

Comment: Updating to the most recent version of Jquery fixed that bug but created a new one.  Now the default jquery mobile css is not applying for some reason.

Comment: Post sample html markup. There have been many changes in latest version.

Comment: From what I can tell, jquery.mobile.structure css and jquery.mobile.them css files are not loading.

Comment: Make sure that custom theme stylesheets should be made to match jQM version

Comment: The theme stylesheets were installed by the same package manger that installed the jQM.  I didn't manually add any of it.

Comment: Turns out they are loading, just not applying for some reason.